# AJAX script does not work

Tags: javascript, ajax

I cannot get the origin IP address from the httpRequest object using the following JavaScript. xhttp.responseText return a null value. I'd appreciate your help.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
       var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 0) {
              document.getElementById("LOCAL_IP").value = xhttp.responseText;
           }
       };
       xhttp.open("GET", "http://11.5.2.218:4080/getIP.jsp", true);
       xhttp.send();
  </script>
```

the getIP.jsp file content is

```
Your IP is <%=request.getRemoteAddr()%>
```

Comment: Why is your status at 0? Change 0 to 200 please and try.

Comment: `xhttp.status` should not be `0` - it should be `200`.

Comment: change `xhttp.status` 0 to 200 Because The 200 status code is by far the most common returned. It means, simply, that the request was received and understood and is being processed.

Comment: I put an alert before the if statement and xhttp.status is alway 0, even when xhttp.readyState reach the status 4 (ready)

Comment: @Fernando use jquery , it's easy and cross browser compatible, you will need to implement separately for all browsers

Comment: Solved. the problem was it never reach 200 because a security issue. I solved that adding: response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); on top op jsp. thank you all

Comment: @ARUN Don't exaggerate. `XMLHttpRequest` can be used the same in all *modern* browsers, and OP's bug is easy to address.

Comment: @this-vidor may be right about modern browsers, I tried this myself a long time ago, I had to make separate objects for internet explorer and another for others, Any way thanks

Comment: @ARUN My understanding is that [even Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support) has dropped support for those browsers that required funky `ActiveXObject` workarounds. That said, I haven't used Windows in ages and cannot test this myself; [this support table](http://caniuse.com/#search=xmlhttprequest) is encouraging.

Answer (score 1):

## Hey,

You need the `xhttp.status` to be equal to `200`, **not** `0`.

For more information about server status codes, read this [HTTP status codes tutorial](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html)

### Try this:

```js
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("LOCAL_IP").value = xhttp.responseText;
  }
};
```